# How Mac keyboard can issue Alt key input in Apache Guacamole

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, guacamole

I am using XFCE terminal in Debian linux on Apache Guacamole from MacOS X.

I'm trying to navigate between tabs in the XFCE's terminal using ALT key shortcuts (e.g. ALT+1 and ALT+2) like shown in the screen below:

[image: xfce using Alt-1,Alt-2 keyboard shortcuts]

I've tried every key combination I can think of, plus researched at places like this. But I haven't yet figured out the secret.

How can I issue these ALT- key combinations from my Mac keyboard in Guacamole?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the modifier key ALT on a PC means "alternate" which would translate to Mac's keyboard symbology as *Option* (on some Macs drawn with a branching-switch icon):
[image: osxdaily: Mac's US-keyboard showing alt keys]

#### Solution (when Guacamole uses realVNC)

According to realVNC (one of the possible connection protocols by Guacamole) your needed ["from Mac to PC" key mapping](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002250597-Keyboard-Mapping-To-and-From-a-Mac#controlling-a-pc-keyboard-from-a-mac-0-1#controlling-a-pc-keyboard-from-a-mac-0-1) would be:

- Pressing "CmdL" (**left *Command* key** on your local Mac) will result in "AltL" (left *Alt* key on the remote PC/Linux)

#### Insightful thoughts

When using Guacamole, which [probably](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#connection-configuration) uses VNC or [XRDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xrdp) protocol to connect your local client (Mac) to the remote server (Linux), the keyboard mapping has to pass 2 layers, from your local hardware/OS (Mac) to browser, over Guacamole/XRDP to the remote-system (Debian with XFCE).
All these layers can interpret the key-events triggered.

#### Research

Like a user of this [XRDP-related forum post from MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-control-your-mac-using-win-rdp-client-xrdp-compiling-guide-on-osx.1770325/post-20982812) (from 2015) explains:

> As below link states, **Alt key** of PC keyboard should be **mapped as Option key** on OS X. This is what we see on ARD. On XRDP Alt key behaves like Windows key and is mapped to Command key.

#### See also:

- RealVNC Help Center: [Keyboard Mapping To and From a Mac](https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002250597-Keyboard-Mapping-To-and-From-a-Mac)
- AskDifferent: [Can't get Alt (Option) key to work while remote controlling a Mac from Windows with VNC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246159/cant-get-alt-option-key-to-work-while-remote-controlling-a-mac-from-windows-w), reverse direction, but might give a clue
- AskUbuntu: [Remote desktop to Ubuntu has wrong keyboard mapping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216230/remote-desktop-to-ubuntu-has-wrong-keyboard-mapping)
- Griffon's IT Library blog: [XRDP – How To Make your keyboard “special keys” (Alt+Gr, Up,Down,..) working when using XRDP](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3858)